# .net settings (WinForms or WPF), when reset to default after recompilation?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I use a serializable (let's call it `Gs`) class within the settings (`user.config`) for some user data. However, sometimes when I recompile my application in VS2012 the settings are gone, means reset to default (basically the default values set in the constructor of the used class). In other cases they persist.

**Actually I was wondering when this is happening.** First I thought, whenever I change `Gs`. But this is not correct, sometimes I have made quite some changes to the class, but when running the application for test changed values remained as previously stored.

On the other hand the values got reset with no changes of `Gs`. Next theory was whenever I change the project's version number. The path to the `user.config` contains the version number.Can this be the reason? But for ClickOnce applications changing the version number has not impact on the settings. Also sometimes the values are reset with no changes of the version number.

So **what is the rule** when the serialized values on disk get wiped out, and when changes do not have an impact. Guess it is a combination, changed version number `or` some other reasons.

[image: Settings in my project]

Comment: Are you adding/changing any of the settings fields (not the values) when this happens?

Comment: I can partly answer that. Sometimes I do - and I understand the failing deserialization in such a scenario. But (this is from memory, so not 100% sure) sometimes I seem to "loose" only that particular value, and there are cases where the values are gone without changes of the class at all - and with no new version number applied. – Horst Walter 18 hours ago